# A Connecting Program.cs And Form.cs

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, static

I have a function in my Form.cs that I want to summon in my program.cs

But if the function is not static, program.cs can't use it. And if it's static, Form.cs can't use it because it involves controls which aren't static.

I can delete my program.cs code and find a way to do the same in my form.cs but I was wondering if there is an easier way.

That's generally what the function in the form.cs does

```
public void Toggle()
    {
        MyDomainUpDown.SelectedIndex = 3;
    }
```

The program.cs :

```
MainForm.Toggle();
```

Comment: It will help to see the function's prototype.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why can't you access it from your program.cs?

You can easily define a variable to hold the form, and then reference it:

```
static class Program
{
    // Any method can now access the form
    static Form1 MyForm;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        MyForm = new Form1();
        Application.Run(MyForm);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your situation is but if you dont have a reference to myForm why or when would you want to call any non static method defined in MyForm?

If on the other hand you have a reference to it, then simply make `MyFunction` public and call it normally:

```
 class Program
 {
     MyForm myForm = new MyForm();
     ....
     myForm.MyFunction(); //call here
 }

 public partial class MyForm: Form
 {
     ....
     public int MyFunction() {...}
 }
```

You can also make it static and add a reference to a MyForm instance in the arguments of the function if there was some practical reason to do so.

```
 public partial class MyForm: Form
 {
     ....
     public static int MyFunction(MyForm myForm) {...}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Form instance is supposedly created in the program.cs so you can access public/internal instance methods from there.

The default implementation of the Program.cs is more or less like this:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}
```

The `new MainForm()` creates the instance of your form. Just assign it to a local variable in order to call its methods:

```
        var mainForm = new MainForm();
        mainForm.MethodToCall();
        Application.Run(mainForm);
```